# How to solve array dimension error when plotting?

Tags: python, arrays, plot, floating-point, dimensions

Based on the code below, I am trying to plot array_frequency_a vs. power_a, but am receiving this error:

```
   ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (201,) and (1,)
```

I know this means that my arrays are different sizes, but how can I change them or create power_a in a different way so that they can be plotted against each other? Thanks!

```
frequency_a=[]
dB_a=[]

a = csv.reader(open('Air.csv'))

for row in itertools.islice(a, 18, 219):
       frequency_a.append(float(row[0]))
       dB_a.append(float(row[1]))
       #print(frequency_a)
array_frequency_a = np.array(frequency_a)       
array_dB_a = np.array(dB_a)

#perform operation on data
for i in range(201):
    power_a = np.array(10**(array_dB_a[i]/10))
    print(power_a)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(array_frequency_a/1e9, power_a, 'b', label='1in air.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to apply some transformation to array_dB_a and then plot against the transformed array. One way to do it more efficiently is to map the function to the array by using `np.vectorize`:

```
power_f = lambda t: 10 ** (t / 10)
vfunc = np.vectorize(power_f)
new_array_dB_a = vfunc(array_dB_a)
```

Then you the new array will have the same dimensions as array_frequency_a:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(array_frequency_a/1e9, new_array_dB_a, 'b', label='1in air.')
```

Comment: This worked absolutely perfectly @alvis! Thank you! It was very simple which I appreciate as a new coder. :D Made my day 1000x easier!